# No se observa la imagen en Tkinter (python)

Tags: python, tkinter, imagen, interfaz-gráfica, programación-funcional

Que hay compañeros;

Estoy empezando a programar, en lo cual me toca hacer una interfaz gráfica de python, en el cual por medio de un boton se elija el archivo jpg y se muestre en la interfaz, pero he tenido un problema, ya que **la imagen no se muestra y en la terminal no me detecta ningun error** y practicamente me vuelvo loco aca les dejo el código

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Label, Text, filedialog, PhotoImage

class Application_BotonPath(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master, width = "1300", height = "950", bg = "old lace")
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.Panel()
        self.widget()
        
    def Panel(self):
        self.frame_side = Frame(self, width = '300', height = '850', bg = 'sky blue').place(x = 20, y = 50)
        self.frame_show = Frame(self, width = '900', height = '850').place(x = 360, y = 50)
        
    def widget(self):
        boton = Button(self.frame_side, text = "Abrir Imagen", command = self.cargar_imagen).place(x = 85, y = 60, width = 150, height = 30)
        salida = Text(self.frame_side, state = "disable").place(x = 43, y = 110, width = 250, height = 700)
        
    def cargar_imagen(self):
        self.ruta_imagen = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Abrir", filetypes = [('Archivo png', '*.png'), ('Archivo jpeg', '*.jpg')])      
        load = Image.open(self.ruta_imagen)
        imagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        label = Label(self.frame_show, image = imagen)
        label.place(x=0, y=0)
        
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Detector de Caracteres")
app = Application_BotonPath(root)
app.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me sale, el cuadro gris que esta en la parte superior derecha supongo que es la imagen, pero no la muestra. por fa ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el objeto `ImageTk.PhotoImage` está definido localmente dentro de la función `cargar_imagen`.

Puedes solucionarlo creando un atributo `self.imagen` en el método `__init__`:

```
self.imagen = None
```

A continuación sustituye `imagen` por `self.imagen` dentro del métoddo `cargar_imagen`:

```
def cargar_imagen(self):
    self.ruta_imagen = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Abrir", filetypes = [('Archivo png', '*.png'), ('Archivo jpeg', '*.jpg')])      
    load = Image.open(self.ruta_imagen)
    self.imagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load) # aquí
    label = Label(self.frame_show, image=self.imagen) # aquí
    label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Realmente no conozco el motivo por el que debe hacerse así para que funcione, supongo que la imágen está siendo manejada por la instancia de `Tk` y no solamente por el `Label` que la contiene. En su día a mi también me dió muchos quebraderos de cabeza este problema.

Un saludo!